# c++ 11 command line parameter separation

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing

I'm pretty new to c++11 and I don't really get it how the command line arguments are parsed into the argv-pointer...

I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string curr_arg = "";

   std::string str_base = "";
   std::string str_subs_file = "";
   std::string str_subs = "";

   for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
   {
       curr_arg = argv[i];

       if(curr_arg == "-b" || curr_arg == "--base")
       {
           str_base = argv[++i];
       }
       else if(curr_arg == "-f" || curr_arg == "--file")
       {
           str_subs_file = argv[++i];
       }
       else if(curr_arg == "-s" || curr_arg == "--subs")
       {
           str_subs = argv[++i];
       }
       else
       {
           std::cout << "Argument '" << argv[i] << "' is not recognised." << std::endl;
           return -1;
       }
   }
}
```

When I call my program with ./subs -b base -s a=1,2,3;b=4,5,6;c=6,7,8 I would expect that I get "a=1,2,3;b=4,5,6;c=6,7,8" as argument when I enter in the `if(curr_arg == "-s" || curr_arg == "--subs"` block instead I just receive "a=1,2,3" and nothing more.
I know it works if I use quotes around the whole argument, but I don't understand why it happen like that..
Is there someone who can explain it to me?

Comment: `;` is a command separator in most shells. This has nothing to do with C or C++.

Comment: as an aside: do you really want to write your own CLI parser? why not use an existing one (`boost::program_options`, ...)?

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the fast answer!
I just thought because it's nothing really difficult it would be an overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not facing a problem with C++ but with your command shell. It is most probably because your shell takes the semicolon as a command seperator.

Your shell interprets your command as `./subs -b base -s a=1,2,3`, then it detects the semicolon and interprets the next command, which is `b=4,5,6` in your case and the same with `c=6,7,8`.

It is pretty much the same as typing (Which should work on most Unix shells):

```
echo abc; sleep 5; echo def 5 seconds later
```

This prints "abc", sleeps for 5 seconds and prints "def 5 seconds later" afterwards.

**Solution:**
To get what you want, you could encapsulate the part `a=1,2,3;b=4,5,6;c=6,7,8` with quotation marks like:

```
./subs -b base -s "a=1,2,3;b=4,5,6;c=6,7,8"
```

or you could escape the semicolon like:

```
./subs -b base -s a=1,2,3\;b=4,5,6\;c=6,7,8
```

Both versions should work with most (if not all) Unix shells and also in the windows cmd, I think.

Comment: Oh i didn't think about this at all...
Thanks for your answer!
Then I do it either as you mentioned it or have to use another separator...